# Sticky nav bar not fully-sticky

Tags: css

when on any page at: https://www.worldwideholidays.co.uk/, when scrolling down, only the bottom half of the nav bar follows. The top part (contact details) does not follow. How can I make it so that the whole half follows?

I tried adding in different elements such as .navbar-extra-top and have no luck.

Example code on the homepage:

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

When scrolled:

```
body #MainMenu.navbar.scrolled {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background: #363c48;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

Comment: Show us the code which shortens the nav when scrolled

Comment: your menu has a `.menu-shrink` class which does `top: -49px !important` - remove it and you'll be fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a minimal code example to demonstrate the issue. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ZoltanToth - Thank you! I literally have just found that! Thanks